# Ignore decimal numbers when using Split() in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I was wondering if there was any way or a pattern to use in the .Split() method so that when I split a sentence by a period, it doesnt split a decimal number (suppose there exists a decimal value in a sentence).

For instance: "Windows Phone **8.1** now has 'Cortana', a Siri-like feature for the platform."

When I Split by period, it will split at the 8.1 number. I would like to SKIP that decimal number as its still part of the the sentence so that when I do split by period, the decimal inside the sentence will still be there.

Comment: Change your split argument to `". "` instead of using `"."`, that way it'll split only on sentences end. May need to split on `".\n"` too however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have a `C#` compiler handy, but the following regex should do the trick.
I tested it in `Java`, which is relatively similar in regex handling.
It will split on any `.` that does not have both a digit before and a digit after.

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(?<!\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<=\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\.(?=\\d)");

string[] output = reg.split(input);
```

I am not sure whether you need to do `\\.` in `C#`, so you may have to play with removing `\\` from in front.

The following code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string input = "Windows Phone 8.1 now has 'Cortana', a Siri-like feature for the platform.";
        Regex reg = new Regex("(?<!\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<=\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\.(?=\\d)");

        string[] output = reg.Split(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output[0]);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Windows Phone 8.1 now has 'Cortana', a Siri-like feature for the platform
```

Comment: @KarimO., Good to know I haven't completely forgotten my C# syntax. :)

Comment: My mistake, although the pattern does work, it still doesn't skip the decimal number, rather it splits on it. So I'm getting something like this: "Windows Phone" "now has Cortana...". I want to keep the number.

Comment: @KarimO., The pattern is intended to *not* split on the period inside. That implies that the regex does not work in C#. I just got a mono compiler, I will test it and updated.

Comment: @KarimO., See the update. I have tested with the full code I provided, and it skips the `8.1` for this test case. Can you provide a test case that breaks?

Comment: @merlin2011 The following will break: `Hello 8.Hi.`, `Hello.9 rabbits.`. I.e. if there is missed space after the period. But if there is always a space, then it is easier to split by period with whitespace following.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, Thank you for the counterexamples. You highlighted the fact that I was only looking for `.` that had numbers on neither side, while I needed to account for `.` with numbers on only one side. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried it again using the sample you posted and it does indeed work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
var output =  Regex.Split(input,@"(?!.*\w)\.");
```